# Does MySql have anything like Oracle JDBC's Database Change Notification?

Tags: mysql, oracle, jdbc

I want the application to be notified when the database is changed.
I can't use trigger. Because we know the DB's connection message, but we can't modify the db. 
So can anyway make application be notified by a connection, like oracle JDBC's [Database Change Notification](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/dbchgnf.htm#JJDBC28815).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So can anyway make application be notified by a connection?

No.

There is a user-defined extension you could use, if you control your MySQL server, to send messages (amqp) from MySQL. You can use that extension in a trigger. https://github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_stomp#readme

Otherwise, you are out of luck on this.  You need to add this notification functionality to the code you use to `INSERT` and `UPDATE` rows in your table.

Comment: Thanks. If it is not be notified by a connection, extension is a feasible method. I just knew a idea, maybe I can use mysql-binlog-connector-java.